# Collecting white dots from completely dark image

Tags: c#, .net, aforge

I am making gamma-spectrometer from webcam. Its matrix covered in foil and image its getting completely dark, but sometimes cosmic/gamma rays or another particle hits matrix and creates a white dot, this dots brightness is indicator of particle energy. My program need to collect these dots brightness into array/list.
My current solution is using AForge. Its  scanning every pixel of the image and finding all white dots, but this takes a lot of time and I am skipping a lot of frames just because scanning of older once is not finished.
Using .Net Core 3.1

My Current code:

```
private void Scan(Bitmap map)
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, map.Width, map.Height);
        BitmapData bmpData = map.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

        int bytes = bmpData.Stride * map.Height;
        byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

        Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);

        int stride = bmpData.Stride;

        for (int column = 0; column < bmpData.Height; column++)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < bmpData.Width; row++)
            {
                Color pixel = Color.FromArgb(rgbValues[(column * stride) + (row * 3)], rgbValues[(column * stride) + (row * 3) + 1], rgbValues[(column * stride) + (row * 3) + 2]);
                if (pixel.GetBrightness() > 0.2) Dots.Add(pixel);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How about sharing some code?

Comment: @Neil Added code to main post

Comment: try move away from 3.1 and to .net 6 plus use all available threads on your machine to process frames see if it works. find better class to work with image - Marshal copy takes a lot of time. try find a managed code for it. and in any case - profile your app - you might be surprised to find the bottleneck in completely inconspicuous place

Comment: C# is just not suited to direct, fast manipulation of GDI data. You would be better off using OpenCV to do this, as it will do exactly what you want, and can manage every frame in a timely manner.